# Link to Document item in SharePoint using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

Programmatically add a "link to a document" content type item in a SharePoint document library using csom.

I have tried to add document manually .is there any link to check how to add item into the Link to document using SharePoint CSOM

Comment: See James11's answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162445/is-it-possible-to-create-a-link-to-a-document-with-rest-or-jsom

Comment: I need CSOM steps ..